# Wordpress:How to Redirect old links after change of Permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

wp old permalinks:

/%category%/%postname%/

and I changed it to: (new permalinks)

/%postname%/

How to Redirect old links after change of Permalinks? with HTACCESS?

thanks

Comment: would you please add more information in terms of the error you are getting ?

Comment: i think wordpress do it by self

Comment: [Check this](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/)

Answer (score 0):

These lines in your htaccess should take care of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:[\w|\-]*)/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -2):

Mostly wordpress will remember your permalink changes and it will redirect traffic from your old url to the new one

Comment: no, wordpress not remember. how can I do with htaccess? thanks

Comment: no, wordpress not remember. how can I do with htaccess? thanks